# Hi, I am trying to input data from nasdaq into R and am getting an error

Tags: r, excel

I am feeding data from the nasdaq into R with this piece of code:

```
nasdaq <- read.table(nasdaqFile, header = TRUE, sep = ",")[,c("Date","Adj.close")]
```

and I am getting this error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(read.table(nasdaqFile, header = TRUE, sep = ","),  :
```

undefined columns selected

The columns in the excel sheets I am using have no errors and are named "Dates" and "Adj.close". please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the name of columns first:

```
nasdaq <- read.table(nasdaqFile, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
print(colnames(nasdaq))
```

Then you can use the correct column names. But, I think you forgot the "s" from the end of "Dates" in your code.

Comment: head(nasdaq)
       Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume Adj.Close
1  2/1/2016 61.96 62.11 60.39 61.74 2113800  60.63555
2 1/29/2016 59.45 62.36 58.71 62.00 2291800  60.89090
3 1/28/2016 57.98 59.85 56.25 58.89 1903700  57.83653
4 1/27/2016 58.74 59.96 57.97 58.30 1714800  57.25708
5 1/26/2016 57.09 58.62 56.76 58.53 1382100  57.48297
6 1/25/2016 57.54 57.99 56.56 56.60 1075400  55.58749

Comment: The header is singular "Date." Your code worked to print the columns I needed, but I am trying to store date and price to create a line of regression with other stock prices using Capital Pricing Asset Model. When I try to extracted the columns i needed I get this error now.

Comment: 'head(nasdaq$Date,nasdaq$Adj.Close)
Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE'

Comment: I tried one more thing and it ended up working out. Thank you for your help